# functional equation in renormalization group theory

Tags: mathematical-physics, functional-equations

In the  Renormalization Group Theory, a key step is the derivation of the so called scaling equation, which in general is in the form of a functional equation of the kind:
$$
g(\mu(\lambda)x,\nu(\lambda)y) = \lambda g(x,y)
$$
where x, y  are real numbers and $\lambda>0$, moreover $\mu(\lambda=1)=\nu(\lambda=1)=1$.

We can assume g differentiable both on x and y and $\mu(\lambda),\nu(\lambda)$ analytic function of $\lambda$.

The (hopefully unique) solution of the functional equation should correspond to $\mu(\lambda)$ and $\nu(\lambda)$ being of the form of power law with two independent exponents.

Is it necessary to add other conditions on the functions $g,\mu$  and $\nu$  to prove this result and its uniqueness? Or is it possible to weaken the hypotheses?

**Edit:**

Assuming $\mu(\lambda)$ being an invertible function (*this is an additional hypothesis*), setting $y=0$ we get 
$$
g(\lambda x,0) = \mu^{-1}(\lambda) g(x,0)
$$
It easy to get
$$
g(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 x,0) = \mu^{-1}(\lambda_1)\mu^{-1}(\lambda_2) g(x,0)=
\mu^{-1}(\lambda_1 \lambda_2) g(x,0)
$$
from which follows (at least for differentiable $ \mu^{-1}(\lambda$):
 $$ \mu^{-1}(\lambda) = \lambda^s$$ and then $ \mu(\lambda) = \lambda^{\frac{1}{s}}$.

My question is if it is necessary to add  an additional hypothesis like that of an invertible $\mu(\lambda)$, if there are alternatives to the invertibility or if is possible to proof the result even under weaker conditions.

Comment: You appear to be writing a malformed [Gell-Mann-Low equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group) for two variables, for a given Wegner function g. If you set y=0, you get [Schroeder's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation). See [this](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.83.065019). Deriving w.r.t. *x*, and, separately,  *y*, and setting $\lambda =1$, you have conditions on $\mu ', \nu '$ relating their exponents, so I fear you are misinterpeting something. The unknown Wegner function is  hard/needless to find.

Comment: What is given, and what are you solving for, and what is a power of what? If g were given, setting y=0 yields $\mu(\lambda)$ by inverting g, and symmetrically for $\nu(\lambda)$, but I am virtually certain this is *not* what you are aiming at.

Comment: @CosmasZachos setting y=0 dooes not give a Schroeder's equation: $\mu(\lambda)$ multiplies $x$ and is not a given function but it is the unknown function of $\lamba$. I'll edito the question to focus better the problem.

Comment: Indeed, for invertible μ(λ) you wrote down the Gell-Mann Low equation, the *starting point* from which you *derive* the scaling equation. Calling $f(x)\equiv g(x,0)$ in your original equation, you invert to Schroeder conjugacy: $\mu(\lambda) x= f^{-1}(\lambda f(x))$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ok,I can see the problem as Schroeder conjugacy. But how does this observation helps me to understand what are the minimal conditions on the functions  which allow to get the result?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, of course, but a response to your last comment question, for lack of ease in making extended comments ... Basically I don't know, but there are stringent constraints among *g,ν,μ* ...

Starting from your 
$$
g(\mu(\lambda)x,\nu(\lambda) y)=\lambda ~ g(x,y),
$$
apply the group property directly, so 
$$
g(\mu(\lambda_1)x,\nu(\lambda_1) y)=\lambda_1 ~ g(x,y)  \Longrightarrow \\
g(\mu(\lambda_1)\mu(\lambda_2)x,\nu(\lambda_1)\nu(\lambda_2) y)=\lambda_1 ~ g(\mu(\lambda_2)x,\nu(\lambda_2)y) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2~ g(x,y) =g(\mu(\lambda_1 \lambda_2)x,\nu(\lambda_1\lambda_2 ) y).
$$

Of course $\mu(\lambda_1)\mu(\lambda_2)=\mu(\lambda_1 \lambda_2)$   and $\nu(\lambda_1)\nu(\lambda_2)=\nu(\lambda_1 \lambda_2)$ satisfy it, but there are entire trajectories $g(x,y)=g(\tilde x, \tilde y)$ that do too, yielding  potentially different *μ,ν*.  Another way to put it is that *g* is not invertible, but has level curves on the *x-y* plane, that is a "symmetry" of *g*.

I  suspect one might have to experiment with toy examples. Take $g=y-x^2$,
so $\mu=\lambda^{1/2}$, and $\nu=\lambda$. But then for small $\epsilon$,
$y\to y+\epsilon$ and $x\to \sqrt{x^2+\epsilon}$ is such a symmetry...

In any case, *μ, ν* are related to and are properties of the Wegner function, as follows from differentiating the top expression w.r.t. *λ* and then setting it equal to 1,
$$
x\mu'(1) \partial_1 g(x,y) +y\nu'(1) \partial_2 g(x,y)=g(x,y), 
$$
where the primes denote derivatives w.r.t.  *λ* at the fixed point, and 1 and 2 w.r.t. the first and second argument, respectively,  of *g* at the fixed point.